# Tap out error message on two places with Axios

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

We have all our api-calls inside a api.js file, which looks like this:

```
import { axiosClient as axios } from 'Utils';

export const urls = {
  getReceiptData: '/purchase/getReceiptData',
  processPurchase: '/purchase/process-purchase',

};

export const getReceiptData = () => axios.get(urls.getReceiptData)
  .then(({ data }) => data);

export const purchaseStatus = purchaseId => axios.get(urls.purchaseStatus.replace('$1', purchaseId))
  .then(({ data }) => data);
```

However, we want to start logging all the error messages to New Relic, while not breaking the functionality of course.

My initial reaction was to receive the error message in this file and handle it here, with something like this:

```
export const purchaseStatus = purchaseId => axios.get(urls.purchaseStatus.replace('$1', purchaseId))
  .then(({ data }) => data, error => newrelic.noticeError(error););
```

But I can't get the same functionality when calling the api.js file from a loop:

```
  pollPurchase = purchaseId => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    .then(() => api.purchaseStatus(purchaseId))
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.state === 'COMPLETED') {
        return true;
      }
      return this.pollPurchase(purchaseId);
    });
```

It seems to break the loop.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios uses promises pattern not the callback one, hence try using this

```
export const purchaseStatus = purchaseId => 
  axios.get(urls.purchaseStatus.replace('$1', purchaseId))
  .then(({ data }) => data)
  .catch(error => { 
    newrelic.noticeError(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
 });
```

It should work as in your solution you are trying to pass a .then 2 callbacks but it only accepts first one and ignores the second one.

And update the pollPurchase method to

```
pollPurchase = purchaseId => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
 .then(() => api.purchaseStatus(purchaseId))
 .then((response) => {
   if (response.state === 'COMPLETED') {
     return true;
   }
   return this.pollPurchase(purchaseId);
 }).catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Thank you! That did help, now it's not getting an error there.
But the functionality in the rest of our app is not continuing now. Is there anything more I need to do in the file calling api.js?

  pollPurchase = purchaseId => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    .then(() => api.purchaseStatus(purchaseId))
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.state === 'COMPLETED') {
        return true;
      }
      return this.pollPurchase(purchaseId);
    });

Comment: @TuxedoJoe what functionality it broke in particular? the change i suggested is not expected to break if your earlier code was working, unless you are not handling the error and always expecting data in response.

Comment: Good question! I've updated the code that didn't continue as before.

Comment: @TuxedoJoe updated the answer, earlier the issue was that i did not reject from catch block, and it meant response in .then of pollPurchase was undefined and hence it caused reference error when you try to do `response.state` of undefined and hence your app was failing, now i threw error , which means the error case will not go to .then, but it will be received in .catch of pollPurchase

Comment: You my man did it! Thank you @MohitYadav 
Added a check for typeof newrelic !== 'undefined' before I ran the newrelic script, since that was giving my strange problems when I got ReferenceError.

Thanks again!

Comment: glad i could help @TuxedoJoe :D